# SQL Server extended events: write custom predicates?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

We have about 2'000 "old" objects in a sql server database (tables, views etc.) of which we don't really know if they're still in use. I want to create an extended event listener for these objects. I tried to add a giant `WHERE` clause to the `CREATE EVENT SESSION` command, consisting of 2'000 `[package0].[equal_int64]([object_id], (<objectId>))` statements.

However, the command max length is 3'000 characters, so I cannot do this. And I guess that the performance of this filer wouldn't be too good, anyway...

Now my question is: I can query all possible predicates using `select * from sys.dm_xe_objects where object_type= 'pred_compare'`. this gives me results such as `name=equal_uint64`, `package_guid=60AA9FBF-673B-4553-B7ED-71DCA7F5E972`. the package_guid refers to `sys.dm_xe_packages`, where several DLLs are referenced which seem to implement a particular predicate.

Would it be possible to define my own "package" and implement a predicate there (which would filter the objectId using a hashtable)? Is it possible somehow to import such a package into SQL server so I could define a custom predicate?

Or does anyone have another idea how to implement such a filter?

Comment: You looking for an answer to your specific question or feedback on ways to determine if objects are still in use?

Comment: I'm looking primarly for an answer for my specific question.